# Не создается отчет Allure в Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, allure

У меня странность. Хочу сделать так чтобы в Jenkins не зависимо от результата прогона создавался отчет.

Я сделал все вроде норм, так как надо, указал параметр в пайплайне.
reportBuildPolicy: "ALWAYS",

Но отчеты не создаются. Почему? Может есть какие то доп настройки или не пайплановские. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.